# strtoi fails to convert string to integer, returns NA

Tags: r

32-bit binary string conversion from string to integer fails. See below

```
strtoi("10101101100110001110011001111111", base=2)
# [1] NA
```

Any ideas what the problem might be ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like `strtoi` cannot handle numbers greater than `2^31`:

```
strtoi("1111111111111111111111111111111", base=2L)
# [1] 2147483647
strtoi("10000000000000000000000000000000", base=2L)
# [1] NA
```

which is the maximum integer my machine (and probably yours) can handle for an integer:

```
.Machine$integer.max
# [1] 2147483647
```

Note that the documentation does warn about overflow (from `?strtoi`):

> Values which cannot be interpreted as integers or would overflow are returned as `NA_integer_`.

What you can do is write your own function that returns the output as a numeric instead of an integer:

```
convert <- function(x) {
    y <- as.numeric(strsplit(x, "")[[1]])
    sum(y * 2^rev((seq_along(y)-1)))
}

convert("1111111111111111111111111111111")
# [1] 2147483647
convert("10000000000000000000000000000000")
# [1] 2147483648
```