# Converting hex format to float numbers in R

Tags: r, hex

could you please someone help me how we can convert 4 byte hex format to float number in R? for example I want to transfer `"aec7a042"` to `80.39` . I could not find anything in R after lots of search to give me this conversion! 
The C function is BitConverter. ToSingle. But I need to do the same in R?
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Can you explain further how your hex digits equal `80.39`?

Comment: Actually the function you mentioned is not a C function, I think you can find a workaround to read binary data, this might be helpful: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/read_binary.htm

Comment: @PierreLafortune - it does seem to fit - e.g. - https://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/ - returns the same result, albeit reversed.

Comment: @thelatemail I get `0x42a0c7ae`. It is close to OP's but far enough to require clarity

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you so much for your help. readBin did not work but the other two codes work properly, I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 6):

Formerly in R you used to be able to read this value directly with  `readBin`. It seems you have a 4-byte signed float value. You can read that with:

```
readBin("aec7a042", "double", size=4)
# [1] 80.39
```

However newer versions of R require just a bit more work. These alternatives should work

```
x <- "aec7a042"
readBin(as.raw(strtoi(substring(x, (step<-seq(1, nchar(x), by=2)), step+1), 16)), "double",n=1,size=4)
# or 
readBin(as.raw(strtoi(apply(matrix(strsplit(x,"")[[1]],2),2,paste, collapse=""), 16)), "double", size=4)
# or 
readBin(as.raw(strtoi(strsplit(x,"(?<=..)",p=TRUE)[[1]],16)), "double", size=4)
```

The idea is that we need to split the string into two character chunks and then convert those chunks to integer values and treat chose values like bytes. That part looks like

```
xraw <- strsplit(x,"(?<=..)",p=TRUE)[[1]] |> # [1] "ae" "c7" "a0" "42"
  strtoi(16) |>                              # [1] 174 199 160  66
  as.raw()                                   # [1] ae c7 a0 42
```

Here we more explicitly convert the character string to a raw vector of bytes. So you see `xraw` contains the same data, but it's not in character form any more, it's an actual "raw" binary vector. And that's what readBin was expecting

```
readBin(xraw, "double", size=4)
# [1] 80.39
```

Comment: Has `readBin` been updated recently? That does not work on R 3.2.4, with an error about the input needing to be binary.

Comment: A more verbose version would be `x<-"aec7a042"; readBin(as.raw(strtoi(substring(x, (step<-seq(1, nchar(x), by=2)), step+1), 16)), "double",n=1,size=4)` using code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251934/how-to-convert-a-hex-string-to-text-in-r

Comment: `readBin(as.raw(strtoi(strsplit(x,"(?<=..)",p=TRUE)[[1]],16)), "double", size=4)` if you want to get fancy.

Comment: @thelatemail Nice. I should have thought of a regular expression.